# Nest thermostat and old HVAC

Tags: hvac, nest

Last year the Nest (used only for cooling) was working after connecting the blue C wire to the HVAC. Last year I made it work only after I put the green wire for the fan in ob.

Now, when the green wire is in ob, the HVAC works and the fan is working too, but when I turn off the system the HVAC is off but the fan does not turn off. If I put the green wire in G the fan works but not the HVAC. I am not sure if that happened after an update.

I guess if someone helps with the proper wire set up it will work as it was working last year. Please see the pictures.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you provide photos of the wiring diagram for your air handler?

Comment: Sure, I will share some more pictures. Please see the additional images.

Answer (score 1):

There are two red wires in your blower.  Assuming the one I labelled below is the one from the thermostat, and the other three wires I labelled are also from the thermostat, *you have this wired correctly*.

Don't use the O terminals.  The thermostat's smart fan controls won't work that way.

Make sure the wires I've labelled in the picture below all come together into one cable and that is the right cable, that goes to your thermostat.  The one I labelled "NOT R" should be unrelated to the thermostat.
[image]

If that is the case, you might have a defective thermostat.   The Nest can run the fan without the cooler but not the other way around.

If you have a voltmeter and continuity tester you can check at the terminal block whether the thermostat is doing what it's meant to do. Using my labels:  R to B should always be 24V-AC.  When the system is off Y to B and G to B should both be 0, when it's on they should both be 24V.  In your phone app, with the system off, you can start up the fan by itself and you should see 24V on G to B.  You can test for broken wires by removing any pair of wires from the thermostat mount, twisting them together, removing them also at the blower and checking continuity between them.

**NOTE**: Turn your breaker off before delving into the blower circuitry.  The terminals on the other side of the metal wall to the transformer are at 240V and are not covered. There may be a power switch nearby that shuts down the blower but does not de-energize all the wires in there.

**Edit** adding diagnostic

Make careful note of where the thermostat wires are connected and disconnect them entirely from the blower.  Then use a spare piece of wire to jumper together power, cool, and fan signals at the unit, like this:
[image]

Turn on the power, and the system should come on.  The fan should come on right away, and the cooling within a few minutes.   Then disconnect your piece of wire from the middle of those three terminals and the cooling should stop but the fan should keep running.   If that all goes as it should, you know the system is ok and the problem is in the thermostat or its wiring.  Otherwise you know the system is the problem.

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer. I added some more pictures that could be helpful.

Comment: I made some changes to the additional text which should be:  Now, when the green wire is in ob, the HVAC works and the fun is working too, but when I turn off the system the HVAc is off but the fun does not turn off. If I put the green wire in G the fan works but not the HVAC. I am not sure if that happened after an update.

Comment: Using G there can be a delay of up to ten minutes or so after the fan turns on before the compressor starts.  Are you waiting?   Your wiring looks correct with G.

Comment: I was not waiting up to 10 minutes but this morning did and nothing happened. The thermostat was in blue color (it seems like working) but neither fan nor compressor were working. There was a bit of a noise but no actual air flow. Please see picture.

Comment: I had this problem before as I said earlier. After talking to Google help they advised me to put the green wire in OB and it worked until recently, but now when green is in B the fan does not show up on the thermostat and app which makes sense.

Comment: That is bad advice.  OB is heat pump control.   It tells the heat pump whether to heat or cool.   If you connect it to an A/C system like this it is approximately, or perhaps exactly, equal to the Y signal.  You could just as easily jumper Y to G, it would do the same thing as OB, probably more reliably.   But these options mean that the thermostats Fan-only programs cannot function.   Honestly the advice from Google is stupid.  Do an experiment ... I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I edited this answer adding a test to see if the system works correctly when you disconnect the thermostat and act as a human thermostat yourself.

Comment: Thanks, I did see the edit. I will try to troubleshoot that later on today or tomorrow. Now, I started having a new problem. Nest does not connect to Wi-Fi and according to online information that might be due to a failing thermostat.